# jQuery 1.8 autocomplete with categories issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

My current code is using jQuery 1.7.x. I am wanting to upgrade to jQuery 1.8 but I'm running into an issue with my autocomplete function. I have created 2 jsfiddles with the same code. In one example, it works correctly, in the other it doesn't. The main problem is when you search, and click, an alert box should show and say what was clicked. It works in the old jQuery but not in 1.8.

Here is the working, 1.7 version - http://jsfiddle.net/u2GEe/1/

Here is the broken, 1.8 version - http://jsfiddle.net/TPWXh/3/

Here is the code:

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category search-dropdown-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = [
    {
    label: "anders",
    category: "aa"},
{
    label: "andreas",
    category: "aa"},
{
    label: "antal",
    category: "aa"},
{
    label: "annhhx10",
    category: "Products"},
{
    label: "annk K12",
    category: "Products"},
{
    label: "annttop C13",
    category: "Products"},
{
    label: "anders andersson",
    category: "People"},
{
    label: "andreas andersson",
    category: "People"},
{
    label: "andreas johnson",
    category: "People"}
];

$("#search_input").catcomplete({
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.label);
    }
});


});​
```

Anyone know what the deal is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending a few days on this I finally figured it out. It was one line:

```
 self._renderItem(ul, item);
```

Now needs to be

```
self._renderItemData(ul, item);
```

After I changed it, everything worked fine again. Very frustrating.

Comment: I'm using jquery ui 1.8.20. And the method to use is : self._renderItem( ul, item );

Answer (score 0):

By logging the values in the `select` callback I noticed that the `item` was `undefined`.

```
$("#search_input").catcomplete({
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(event, ui); // DEBUG
        alert(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

Not sure why jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.9.1 doesn´t work together but I got it working by using jQuery UI **1.8.2** instead of 1.9.1.

Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3mgSG/).